# Raspberry Pi 4 LED light blinking only blinks around 9 times, not continuously

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have used the below Python code for Raspberry Pi 4 to have LED light blink continuously but I only blinks for around 10 times and stops. I need it to blink continuously.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

redLED = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(redLED, GPIO.OUT)

try:
   while True:
      GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.HIGH)
      time.sleep(0.5)
      GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.LOW)
      time.sleep(0.5)

finally:
   GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up the GPIO channel in every iteration.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

redLED = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

try:
   while True:
      GPIO.setup(redLED, GPIO.OUT)
      GPIO.output(redLED, True)
      time.sleep(0.5)

      GPIO.output(redLED, False)
      time.sleep(0.5)

finally:
   GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Its still the same thing. LED gets weak and off.

Comment: Hmm perhaps it's hardware? Could you try the same script but written in C? Perhaps there are some tutorials for a quick script. I have a RPi 3BP and the python script works fine.